# How to align mesh for Seamless Texture Baking?

Tags: texturing, texture-baking

I'm trying to create a chainmail pattern in Cycles by creating interlinking chains, and then baking them using an Emission shader to generate a black and white image, to then use as a Bump Map and mask to generate a mail material and texture. I only modelled two chains and then used Arrays to make copys of them.

[image]

The problem though, is that I can't seem to align the Camera in a way that generates me a seamless texture.

[image]

As you can see, the result is not seamless and it's very obvious, so how can I align the camera perfectly that makes the baking a lot more easy.

Blend: [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things to make it work.

**1. Make your camera Orthographic**
This will help you avoid distortion in corners, and will make it 'infinitely flat'.
It's like using an infinitely long lens.

[image]

**2. Make the array 1:1 aspect ratio**
Your chainmail array is ever so slightly taller-than-wide.
Move the rings a bit along the X axis, so they fit nicely.

Voilá. Seamless.

[image] [image]

**Notes**
If you want the mail evenly-spaced, you'll have to adjust the whole array (I was just lazy).
I also moved the camera a bit, instead of moving the whole array.

Adjusted .blendfile is here

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help! Can't believe I forgot to switch the camera to orto for this. : P

Comment: Don't beat yourself up about it, happens to everyone :). Good luck with your project.